# Running JMeter script with one click and generating results

Tags: batch-file, jmeter

I need to run a JMeter script placed at XYZ location and then want to generate result date and timewise for different execution run. Can we do that with the help of a *.BAT* file?

If yes please assist me on this.

Comment: As you've accepted an answer, I've edited your tags and question to remove `shell` and `.sh`.

Comment: "Assisting" implies that you have done some work on your own, so please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Tony, you can surely do that. I had used it in the past for one of my scripts and it worked. Pasting in the *.bat* file content below. For .sh file you will have to do few changes in that which you can google out. Below is the .bat file content:

```
@echo off

set UserProperties="give user.properties file location here"
set SystemProperties="give system.properties file location here"

set /p ThreadGroup=Enter the number of virtual users: 
set /p RampUpTime=Enter the ramp up peroid: 
set /p LoopCount=Enter the loop count value: 
set /p BaseURL=Enter the base URL: 

mkdir local location\TestResult_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%  ---- Make a folder with timestamp appended to store in your result

set Output1="local location\TestResult_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"

echo User Inputs Entered For The Test Are: >>%Output1%\TestInput_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
echo ThreadGroup=%ThreadGroup% >> %Output1%\TestInput_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
echo RampUpTime=%RampUpTime% >> %Output1%\TestInput_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
echo LoopCount=%LoopCount% >> %Output1%\TestInput_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
echo BaseURL=%BaseURL% >> %Output1%\TestInput_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt

echo Test Input File has been placed at %Output1%

e: 
cd apache-jmeter-3.2\bin  ( Go to the bin folder where JMeter is installed)

jmeter -n -t E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\scripts\SampleTestPlan.jmx -l E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\results\TestResult_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%\TestResult_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.csv -j E:\apache-jmeter-3.2\bin\results\TestResult_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%\Testlogs_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log -JThreadGroup=%ThreadGroup% -JRampUpTime=%RampUpTime% -JLoopCount=%LoopCount% -JBaseURL=%BaseURL%   ---- Finally run the command to start non gui mode execution.
```

As a result of this, a folder will be created at the specified location with the input file, log file and the *.CSV* file with all the results.